# Which is the first version of gdb which contains dprintf?

Tags: gdb

My system has gdb 7.2 and 7.4, which both do not have dprintf feature. I checked the release page at https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/ and it does not say which version first released the feature.

I am trying to avoid using the latest gdb because I fear it might require new version dependent libraries and I have no admin privilege to install them. So I would like to know which is the first version beyond 7.4 which contains dprintf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to avoid using latest gdb because I fear it might require new version dependent libraries and I have no admin privilege to install them.

gdb's dependencies are pretty minimal.  I doubt this will be a real problem.  Also, if it is, you can also build and install libraries without requiring any special permissions.

That said, gdb documents major new features in the "NEWS" file.  You can [find it online](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/NEWS;hb=HEAD) in the gdb git repository.  Looking there, it seems that `dprintf` was added in 7.5.  But, I somewhat recall that early on `dprintf` had some bugs and you should probably try something newer.